# C program to sort words from text files and print their frequency using linked lists but frequency is not getting calculated

Tags: c, linked-list

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include<malloc.h>
#include<ctype.h>

#define WS " ,\t!:;.-" 
#define MAX_STR_LEN 1024 

int i;

struct listNode {
    int count;
char *word;
struct listNode *next;

}       //Definition of a structure

struct listNode *newListNode(const char * const);
void insertWord(struct listNode *,const char * const);
void printList(struct listNode *);
int countlist(struct listNode *);
 int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  FILE *fp;
static int j=0;
    char line[MAX_STR_LEN],*s,tem[99];
struct listNode *head = newListNode("");

   if(argc<2)
    {
    exit(0);
    }
  for(i=1;i<argc;i++)
  {

 fp = fopen(argv[1],"r")
 if(fp==0)
    {
    perror(argv[i]);
    continue;
    }
 {
    while (fgets(line,MAX_STR_LEN,fp) != NULL) 
    {
        *(strchr(line,'\n')) = '\0';
          for (s = strtok(line,WS); s != NULL; s = strtok(NULL,WS))
            {
             insertWord(head,s);
             }
    }
    printList(head);

    fclose(fp);
} 
else {
    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("usage: %s <filename>\n",argv[0]);
    } else {
        printf("%s not found.\n",argv[1]);
    }
    }
    }   return 0;
    }


   /* 
   *   * newListNode: create new struct listNode 
    *     */
     struct listNode *newListNode(const char * const s) {
      struct listNode *n =
     (struct listNode*)malloc(sizeof( struct listNode ));
  n->word = (char *)malloc(sizeof( *s ) );
  strcpy(n->word,s);
 n->next = NULL;
  return n;
 }

  /* 
   *   * insertWord: insert given word into list in ascending order 
   *     */
  void insertWord(struct listNode *head,const char * const s) {
struct listNode *p = head,
    *q = newListNode(s);
p->count=p->count+1;
while ((p->next!= NULL) &&
              (strcmp(s,p->next->word) < 0))
    {
    p = p->next;
}
q->next = p->next;
p->next = q;

}
```

//To display the list of words

```
  void printList(struct listNode *head) {
   struct listNode *p = head->next;
   while (p != NULL) {
 printf("%5d %s\n",countlist(head),p->word);
 p=p->next;
}
puts("");

}
```

//Function to count the frequency of a word

```
   int countlist(struct listNode *head) {
   struct listNode *p = head->next;

while (p != NULL) {
 if(strcmp(p->word,p->next->word)==0)
p->count=p->count+1;
p=p->next;
 }
return(p->count);
 }
```

My program is basically to use a linked list to read words from multiple text files. Sort them in a alphabetical way (ASCII values) and then also count how many times each word is there.

Answer (score 0):

So a few things,

```
    fp = fopen(argv[1],"r");
    if(fp==0)
    {
        perror(argv[i]);
        continue;
    }
```

Really needs to be compared to NULL, not zero.

**fopen** man page:
    "Upon successful completion fopen(), fdopen(), and freopen() return a FILE
     pointer.  Otherwise, NULL is returned and the global variable errno is set
     to indicate the error."

**Sanity saver:** if you rearrange your comparison statements to have the value as the left-hand value your compiler will not allow the accidental assignment statement. Not just for this problem, just about any comparison.
i.e.

```
    if(NULL==fp){
        perror(argv[1]);
        continue;
    }//end if
```

OR

```
    if(0==strcmp(p->word,p->next->word)){
        //code to do stuff
    }//end if
```

On to the frequency problem, are you referring to **countList()** not returning a proper integer? Why not just use an integer to hold the count and return that or do you want each node to have its relative frequency in it's struct?

Answer (score 0):

In `countlist()`, this is wrong:

```
while (p != NULL) {
 if(strcmp(p->word,p->next->word)==0)
```

Since the list node which `p->next` points to is accessed, you must assert that `p->next` is not null:

```
    while (p->next)…
```